# The Category of Groups and Conjugacy Classes of Homomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

Algebraic topology begins with the observation that we can put an equivalence relation on the set of maps between two given spaces, namely homotopy. Studying this category of topological spaces and maps modulo this equivalence relation has been fruitful to say the least.

Given two groups $G$ and $H$, we can similarly put an equivalence relation on $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{Grp}}(G,H)$ by declaring $\alpha,\beta:G \to H$ to be equivalent if there is some $h\in H$ such that $h\cdot \alpha(g) \cdot h^{-1} = \beta(g)$ for all $g \in G$. In other words, two group homomorphisms are declared to be equivalent if they differ by an inner automorphism.

My question is whether or not it is also fruitful to study the category of groups and group homomorphisms modulo this equivalence relation. Immediately, it is clear that many of the things we talk about in introductory algebra (e.g. conjugacy classes, the class formula, normal subgroups) can be described using this category, so perhaps the study of this category would simply produce the same results. But perhaps not. In particular, I have the gut feeling that some results may be stated more cleanly, though I am not sure.

**Edit 10/23/2016**

Some observations: let's call the category in question $\mathcal{C}$. Some interesting things to note are that $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(\mathbb{Z}, G)$ is exactly the set of conjugacy classes of $G$.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how taking conjugacy classes of group homomorphisms this is related to algebraic topology?

Comment: @SunghyukPark, I'm declaring two group homomorphisms $\alpha, \beta: G \to H$ to be conjugate if there is some $h \in H$ with $h \cdot \alpha(g) \cdot h^{-1} = \beta(g)$ for all $g\in G$

Comment: @sunghyukPark, and yes, this is (admittedly loosely) related to algebraic topology. If we have two connected based spaces $X,Y$, then the fundamental group gives a function $[X,Y]_* \to \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{Grp}}(\pi_1X, \pi_1Y)$, where $[-,-]_*$ is the set of based homotopy classes of maps . If instead we look at free homotopy classes of maps, the fundamental group gives a function $[X,Y] \to \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(\pi_1 X, \pi_1 Y)$.

Comment: Note this is precisely example 1.1.1.1 in Lurie's HTT.

Comment: Maybe what we really want is the $2$-category of groups, homomorphisms and conjugations between homomorphisms.