# Is there a way to study the relationship between the category of finite groups and their conjugacy classes categorically?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, category-theory

I asked this question on MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/467524/525141)

---

From [The influence of conjugacy class sizes on the
structure of finite groups](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=c3f89a7137a3353aJmltdHM9MTcxMTA2NTYwMCZpZ3VpZD0xNTYyNGMzZC0xNWI3LTY5OWEtM2Y1ZS01Zjk0MTQ2NDY4NWMmaW5zaWQ9NTE5Mw&ptn=3&ver=2&hsh=3&fclid=15624c3d-15b7-699a-3f5e-5f941464685c&psq=influencbof+conjugacy+classes&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9hcnhpdi5vcmcvcGRmLzEwMDIuMzk2MC5wZGY&ntb=1).

My question is as follows: Is there a way to study the relationship between the category of finite groups and their conjugacy classes categorically? Could you please provide references for this?

Clarification of the question: we know the impact of conjugasy classes in classification the finite groups but however there are open questions dose not have answers yet so my main gaol is to find a way to connect category of finit groups and conjugacy classes categorically to solve such questions.

I found [The category of groups and conjugacy classes of homomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1980881/1303644) Is it relevat to my question from algebraic topology Perspective?

Comment: This does not do justice to your question, but it's worth noting that a group action for a group $G$ is just a functor $G\to Set$, where $G$ is considered as a category.  If you let $F:G\to Set$ be the conjugation action on $G$, then $S=F(G)$ is the set being acted upon, and $F(a)$ for each arrow is an element of $Sym(S)$, so you might write $a$ acting on $s\in S$ like $F(a)(s)=asa^{-1}\in S$.  If you hold $s$ fixed and vary $a$ you recover the conjugacy class of $s$.  No doubt there is categorical jargon to make this familiar.

Comment: Two homomorphisms between groups are conjugate if and only if they are naturally isomorphic as functors between one-object categories.